# C program to create 3 child processes which read from 3 different files

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, pipe

I have this question how to a write a **C program** that creates 3 child processes which read from 3 different files and write to the  **parent process using pipes**.

Each child should wait a random amount of time (3 -10 seconds) between writing each 50 characters.

The father should read from **pipes** and
**write** everything he gets (from all 3 files) into one new file.

Comment: What did you try? Did you read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)? Show your code please.

Comment: @Bha making random words **bold** is not proper formatting of text.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer by Rachit Jain, you could create an array with the filenames, and use the loop counter as an index into the array to know which file each child process should open. Works best when each child process should process the files the same, just do it in parallel.

As for the pipes, you really need three different pipes, one per child process, or the data from the children might become mixed. Use e.g. [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) or [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html) to check for input from the different pipes.

Comment: Thank you joachim can you expand it more with an example ?

Comment: One pipe is sufficient, and writes that are smaller than the pipe buffer size (which is more than 50 bytes, so all the writes are safe) will be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first.

You first need to create the 3 pipes with the [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) syscall (repeated 3 times).

You then need to create the 3 child processes with the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall. Handle the 3 possible return values of `fork`: `<0` on failure, `==0` in child, `>0` in parent. Remember the `pid_t` in parent. In each child call [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) to have the `STDOUT_FILENO` be the output of relevant pipe.

At last, in the parent, make a simplistic [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), using the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) multiplexing syscall to find out which pipe should be [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

Use [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) and [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) in the child, but don't forget to seed -using `srand`- the [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) with something random (like its pid gotten by [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) added to the current [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html)....; or use `/dev/urandom` see [urandom(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/urandom.4.html))

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) commented, since 3*50 is less than `PIPE_MAX`, you might perhaps use a single pipe. I feel that using an event loop is more safe and more general (it will work if you replace 50 by 500000 which is greater than `PIPE_MAX`).

<sup>I don't think I want or have time to do more of your homework for you. I gave you enough hints above.</sup>

I believe that [Federos Koros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3125382/fedoros-koros) `fedoroskoros@gmail.com` is very wrong in [trying to pay someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720099/c-programming-using-pipes-and-linux-operation-system) to do his homework, and I did sent him a private email about that.  The question is now deleted.

Comment: One pipe would be sufficient, and safe.  And avoids the need to poll.

Answer (score 0):

fork () three times in a loop with a variable ,say i, and below put conditions for i=0 , i=1 and i=2. in each each condition read one of your file.

rest won't be tough task either now.

Comment: thank you very much rachit can you explain it more in a detailed example ?